# Defining Contours Over Aplhabets

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on OCR for my project. So far I am focusing on Image Processing   part. And now I want to define contours over the alphabets in my images. I have binarized images.[Test Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qClLj.jpg) The code for the same is:

```
import pymongo
import json
from bson import json_util
import cv2



img = cv2.imread("./uploads/Form.jpg")


myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")

mydb = myclient["mydatabase"]
mycol = mydb["customers"]

docs_list = list(mycol.find())

xy = docs_list[0]['dimensions']

for i in docs_list:
    cropped_image = img[i['dimensions']['y']: i['dimensions'['y']+i['dimensions']['height'], i['dimensions']['x']: i['dimensions']['x']+i['dimensions']['width']]
    temp = cv2.cvtColor(cropped_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(temp, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    cv2.imwrite(f'{i["fieldName"]}.jpg', im_bw)
```

I am getting the correct output for the binarized image. I just want help to define contours over alphabets in images.

Comment: It would be hard to define the contours because of the horizontal line present in the image.

Comment: It will be removed because I will be applying Hough line transformation.

Comment: Then please upload the final image after applying Hough Line Transfrom ?

Comment: I have uploaded the final image. See if you can help:).